# Azure OpenAI Search Service and Azure OpenAI Studio - Unsupported File Types and Citations

Tags: azure-openai

I create an Azure OpenAI Search Service app and it's configured with an index that has multiple indexers which source data from SharePoint documents.

I create my model in Azure OpenAI Studio and deploy it to a web app. I'm able to converse with my documents through the web app. See below:

[image: Chat with own data]

Here's the challenges...

Only the following file types are supported, so how do I index images, emails, Excel, etc?

- .txt
- .md
- .html
- .pdf
- Microsoft Word files (.doc, .docx)
- Microsoft PowerPoint files (.ppt, .pptx)

Then, when clicking a reference in the response, the citations window shows an unformatted extract of the document. How can I show this in a formatted way, alternatively I would like to see the full path of the document that was cited so I can open the original document with all formatting in place.

Is this possible, if so, how? Wasn't able to find an acceptable solution on the web and Microsoft's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you are showing is an accelerator provided in Azure AI Studio to quickly demonstrate basic capabilities regarding documents processing.

If you want to go deeper, like indexing other kind of documents, you have to understand what runs behing this sample, which is Azure AI Search service (formerly Azure Cognitive Search).

All the data you provided initially has been proccesed and indexed so it explains why you have this 'unformatted' document on the right side, which is how it is stored in the index.

You can customize your experience by:

- completing the existing index using code, for example for processing the other kind of source files (you will have to manage the process to read the file, chunk it into smaller pieces if needed, and vectorize if needed, before inserting those items - called 'documents' in the index)
- improving the display of the sample web app for the source display: it is open-sourced, here: https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT/ You could for example make a button to open the original source file (if you keep a link to it in a field of your index), but keep in mind that you will need access to this source document if you want to access it directly (and not its indexed content), so a lot of questions regarding permissions